# ActiveMQ JMS bridge polling interval

Tags: activemq-classic

I plan to use JMS bridge feature of ActiveMQ in order to synchronize my local ActiveMQ Queue with a remote Websphere MQ Queue. I think that the JMS bridging feature is basically polling the WMQ Queue, isn't it ? In this case where can I define the polling duration interval ?

Tks a lot
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActiveMQ JMS Bridge does not poll, the bridge uses the client library from the broker to be bridged and registers an async consumer to receive incoming messages from the remote Broker.  There's nothing to configure in regards to polling.

Comment: Hello, thanks so if I understand correctly , ActiveMQ will open one session against WMQ, I suppose that in case of high volume of messages to retrieve , it will create a bottleneck , how to handle high volume ? Tks Nicolas

Comment: Use Apache Camel as the bridge and then you can use patterns like Throttle etc.